# Kotlin - Get Class<T> from KProperty1<T, P>

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Given the following class:

```
data class Foo(val bar: Int)
```

How would I obtain a `Class<T>` for `Foo`...

```
val prop = Foo::bar
```

...from this property expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val receiver = prop.parameters[0]
val receiverClass = receiver.type.jvmErasure.java
```

Note that you get `KType` and `KClass` on the way, which you may prefer to `Class`.

The above works because `parameters` documentation [says](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/parameters.html)

> If this callable requires a this instance or an extension receiver parameter, they come first in the list in that order.

so it might be worth a comment in your code.

The receiver parameter can also be obtained more explicitly by

```
val receiver = (prop.instanceParameter ?: prop.extensionReceiverParameter)!!
```

Comment: @Roland A static function isn't a `KProperty1` :) I only said one of them should be non-null in the context of the question.

Comment: @Roland Actually, good point, changed to `prop.parameters[0]`, no `!!` required then.

Comment: @Roland I added it back with some discussion. I'd prefer the more explicit version too if it only didn't need `!!`.

Comment: on the other hand `parameters[0]` or `parameters.first()` just hide the fact, that it can fail... `!!` is explicit about it ;-) ... but these are all just details the implementors have to decide ;-) I like it that way... but that's me... I like more information, so I can decide ;-)